# Perforce integration to few branches

Tags: integration, perforce, branching-and-merging, p4v

I have depot structure like:

```
- DEV
- MAIN
- REL1.0
- REL1.1
- REL1.2
- ...
- REL2.0
```

From time to time I face with issue to integrate some "hot fix" from DEV branch to all REL branches. I tried to make this with the help of branch mapping like this:

```
//DEV/... //REL1.0/...
//DEV/... //REL1.1/...

//DEV/... //REL2.0/...
```

But as result I have shelve with files integrated only in last (REL2.0) branch.
Is any way to integrate patch in few branches with the help of p4v?
Or may be way to automate this process with the help of p4?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Indeed, when you have multiple mappings for the same file, each mapping overrides the previous one, and so the last mapping (REL2.0) in your case is the one chosen by the integrate command when you use that mapping. You can, of course, integrate using a pair of file specs instead, but you'll need to issue the integrate+resolve commands once for each branch (then submit all the integrations as a single changelist if that's the result you desire).

Comment: Yes, such way I'm using now. But it is routine in the case of a large number of branches.